# repetitive header/footer issue on creating ms word document using apache poi

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I have a project which creating ms word document. In this word document, I want to create header/footer. To do this I wrote this codes

```
public static void header_footer(String SalesOrder,String type) throws InvalidFormatException, IOException
    {

        XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy headerFooterPolicy = document.getHeaderFooterPolicy();   

          if (headerFooterPolicy == null) 
              headerFooterPolicy = document.createHeaderFooterPolicy();

              XWPFHeader header = headerFooterPolicy.createHeader(XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy.DEFAULT);
              XWPFTable asd= header.createTable(1, 2);
              asd.setTableAlignment(TableRowAlign.LEFT);
              XWPFTableRow row;
              XWPFTableCell cell,cell2;
              CTHeight ht;
              CTTrPr trPr;
              CTTblWidth cellWidth;
              row= asd.getRow(0);
              trPr = row.getCtRow().addNewTrPr();
              ht = trPr.addNewTrHeight();
              ht.setVal(BigInteger.valueOf(-1070));         
              cell=row.getCell(0);        

              XWPFParagraph parag=document.createParagraph();
              parag = cell.getParagraphArray(0);
              XWPFRun r1=parag.createRun();


              InputStream pic = access_connection.class.getResourceAsStream("page1_header.png");


              r1.addPicture(pic, XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, imgFile2, Units.toEMU(160), Units.toEMU(55)); 


                cellWidth = cell.getCTTc().addNewTcPr().addNewTcW();            
                cellWidth.setW(BigInteger.valueOf(3500));
                cell2=row.getCell(1);
                cellWidth = cell2.getCTTc().addNewTcPr().addNewTcW();           
                cellWidth.setW(BigInteger.valueOf((short)20000));


            parag=cell2.getParagraphArray(0);
            parag.setVerticalAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
            parag.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
            cell2.setVerticalAlignment(XWPFVertAlign.CENTER);
            XWPFRun r2=parag.createRun();
            r2.setFontSize(14);
            r2.setFontFamily("Calibri");
            r2.setText("TURKISH ENGINE CENTER SHOP VISIT REPORT");
            r2.addBreak();
            r2.setText("ESN "+SalesOrder.substring(1, 7)+"                         Istanbul,TURKEY");

            XWPFFooter footer = headerFooterPolicy.createFooter(XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy.DEFAULT);
            XWPFParagraph parag2= footer.createParagraph();
            XWPFRun run3=parag2.createRun();
            XWPFRun run4=parag2.createRun();
            run3.setFontFamily("Arial");
            run4.setFontFamily("Arial");
            run3.setBold(true);
            run4.setItalic(true);
            run3.setFontSize(8);
            run4.setFontSize(9);
            run3.setText("U.S. Export Classification: EAR ECCN 9E991");
            run3.addBreak();
            run4.setText("Printed by TEC Local EVM System");
            XWPFParagraph parag3= footer.createParagraph();
            XWPFRun run5=parag3.createRun();
            parag3.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.RIGHT);
            run5.setFontSize(7);
            run5.setFontFamily("Arial");
            run5.setText("Page ");
            run5.getCTR().addNewPgNum();

//          footer.setCommited(true);




        try {


                FileOutputStream input = new FileOutputStream(word_saveas_file+SalesOrder+"_"+type+"_Report.docx");

                document.write(input);
                input.close();  
//              input.flush();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I'm running my project from .jsp web page on tomcat server. When I run my project first time, everything running correctly. But when I run my project second time without stopping or restarting tomcat server, header/footer is repeating. I don't understand why only header/footer repeating. I'm creating ms word documents which are different names but still have this problem.

```
public static void Start(String SalesOrder, String path,String type) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

      baslik[0]="ATA";  
      baslik[1]="LID";
      baslik[2]="PN";
      baslik[3]="QPE";
      baslik[4]="SV";
      baslik[5]="IS";
      baslik[6]="RS";
      baslik[7]="REP";
      baslik[8]="Defect";

      baslik2[0]="PN";
      baslik2[1]="NEW";
      baslik2[2]="REP";
      baslik2[3]="SV";
      baslik2[4]="Information Only";

     try {
        start_page_1(SalesOrder,path,type);
    } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
         try {
            start_page_2(SalesOrder,type);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            header_footer(SalesOrder,type);
        } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        eng_general(SalesOrder);
        oil_sys(SalesOrder);
        GroupName(1);
        partoff(SalesOrder,type);

    //baglanti= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://"+db_file,db_username,db_password);
      //sorgu=baglanti.createStatement();
     //deneme=sorgu.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM TableRun");
        System.out.println("Process Completed");


    }
public static void Start_PDM(String SalesOrder, String path,String type) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, IOException {

      baslik[0]="ATA";  
      baslik[1]="LID";
      baslik[2]="PN";
      baslik[3]="QPE";
      baslik[4]="SV";
      baslik[5]="IS";
      baslik[6]="RS";
      baslik[7]="REP";
      baslik[8]="Defect";

      baslik2[0]="PN";
      baslik2[1]="NEW";
      baslik2[2]="REP";
      baslik2[3]="SV";
      baslik2[4]="Information Only";

     try {
        start_page_1(SalesOrder,path,type);
    } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
         try {
            start_page_2(SalesOrder,type);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            header_footer(SalesOrder,type);
        } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        GroupName(1);
        partoff(SalesOrder,type);
        /*try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM java.exe");
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("net start java");
            System.exit(0);
        } catch (Throwable e) {

        }   */
        baglanti.close();

    //baglanti= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://"+db_file,db_username,db_password);
      //sorgu=baglanti.createStatement();
     //deneme=sorgu.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM TableRun");
        System.out.println("Process Completed");


    }
```

I'm using first method for create word document with `eng_general` and `oil_sys` methods. In the second method I'm creating word document without `eng_general` and `oil_sys`.

Comment: How gets the method `header_footer` called? Seems it gets called multiple time for the same document.

Comment: @AxelRichter I'm calling it two times for different .jsp pages and different servlets. I'm adding codes my question.

Comment: If both the methods are using the same `XWPFDocument document`, then it is pretty clear why the contents of the header and footer gets repeated. The code creates a new table in header and a new paragraph in footer of the document each time it runs.

Comment: @AxelRichter Ok, I solve problem. I was creating `XWPFDocument document` at outside of methods. I tried to create it inside of `Start` method then it worked.